# Supremum and Infimum for sequence that is not monotone increasing or decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I understand the concept of supremum and infimum for monotone increasing or decreasing sequence, but this one is different. I know that for monotone increasing/decreasing sequences, you should find the upperbound and lowerbound first, and the process is usually straightforward.

I need help to find supremum and infimum of the sequence

$$(-1)^n + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$for $n=1$ to infinity.

I tried calculating the first 5 terms of this sequence, which are 0, 1/2, -2/3, 3/4, and -4/5. From first glance, I cannot determine the upper or lower bounds. I do have an idea that I could perhaps separate the negative and positive terms, so {1/2, 3/4,...} and {0, -2/3, -4/5,...}
From this, I can see that 1/2 is the lowerbound for the positive term, and 0 is the upperbound for the negative term.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Since the calculation is easy, the beginning of your sequence could be graphed by hand, to perhaps see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is even, say $n=2k\;(k\geqslant 1)$, $$a_{2k} \;=\;(-1)^{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k}\;=\;1-\frac1n\;>\;0.$$

If $n$ is odd, say $n=2k-1\;(k\geqslant 1)$, $$a_{2k-1} \;=\;-1+\frac1n\;\leqslant\;0.$$

So, for all $k$ and for all $m$, we have $a_{2k}>a_{2m-1}.$ Thus to find the overall supremum, you need only find the supremum of what you call the positive terms.

Since you understand the concept of supremum for a monotone increasing sequence, I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Is what I wrote clear to you, Bam?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. I can finally conclude that the Infimum is -1, and the Supremum is just 1.